# Firebase Authentication error in Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, dart-pub

I am getting the error ***Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'AssertionErrorImpl'*** while attempting to sign in using the FirebaseAuth.

Below is my code:

`AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);`